# Каким образом начислять бонусы пользователю 1-раз в 24-часа?

Tags: php, mysql, обновление

Приветствую. Каким образом возможно будет начислять пользователю бонусы 1-раз в 24-часа, как в режиме онлайн так и в режиме офлайн, когда пользователя нет на сайте.

Цель: По php - начислять каждые 24-часа бонус определённого количества пользователю.
Пример: Пользователь зашел на сайт, система начисляет ему бонус, пользователь не зашел на сайт система будет всё равно начислять ему бонус (если это возможно по php)

Пример кода в котором я не знаю как правильно написать условия начисления бонуса:

```
if(time() > 1){ // Как правильно написать здесь условия, что каждые 24-часа начисляй пользователю бонус?
$bonus = "500";
$query = mysqli_query($dbConn, "UPDATE `D_Users` SET `bonus` = bonus + " . $bonus . " WHERE `id` = '1'"); //Начисляем бонус пользователю к примеру с ID-1
}
```

Только посредством - PHP
Без крона и т.д

Answer (score 1):

Запускай скрипт начисления бонусов через крон, условия не надо просто `0 0 * * * php /var/www/site.com/bonus.php`, каждые 24 часа в полночь будет всем бонус

Comment: Посредством php без крона

Comment: Пиши демона и изобретай свой крон если таковой отсутствует, но советую купить нормальный хостинг